# eclipse, django, pydev - slow update with the script?

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

It's weird. Let say I make a minor change in my view or urls file. I do "Run as -> PyDev: Django", and it takes several times to update it....

and most of the time I have keep doing it.... I cleaned the cache and all that, but doesn't help.

I am using the development server, anyone has experience in this?

Thanks!!

---

Edit
It seems like the only work-around for me is to run manage.py startserver via the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had issues with stray python processes using PyDev + django's runserver in auto-reload mode.  For that reason I always run using the `--noreload` option and restart the process each time I make a change.

Comment: i actually had that enabled... runserver --noreload  guess it's a bug... probably have to use my work-around then :) but thank you for sharing your experience

Comment: If you do `sudo netstat -alpn | grep 8000` after terminating everything in eclipse, do you see that eclipse is listening on the port?

Comment: i am actually a windows user... sorry :(

Comment: `netstat -aon | findstr "8000"` will get the PID, then check the task manager.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, PyDev has something builtin to ease in that.

See: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html (in the end of the page) for a solution which allows you to have debug with auto-reload and a way to see in a shell even when it's executed from PyDev.